# How to restart GNOME Shell from command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell

I would like to implement a keyboard shortcut to restart gnome-shell whenever this one crashes ([some bugs](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance%20desc&bug_status=__open__&product=gnome-shell&content=crash) aren't currently fixed just yet). For this I would need a command line to restart the shell.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `restart` command won't work when the shell is crashed because the prompt is implemented **in** the shell.

Hence, how to restart the gnome-shell from command line?

Comment: NOTE: Alt+F2 and `restart` will stop all the running programs. (I still don't know how to restart the GUI without stopping the programs.)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

### GNOME Shell 3.30.1 on Ubuntu 18.10

The command to replace `gnome-shell` would be sending a [SIGQUIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGQUIT) signal to it with:

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

or:

```
killall -SIGQUIT gnome-shell
```

As of GNOME Shell 3.30.1 on Ubuntu 18.10, the solution below no longer works, and will kick the user to the login screen, losing all of their work.

### Before GNOME Shell 3.30.1

The command to replace `gnome-shell` would be:

```
gnome-shell --replace &
```

The ampersand is added to return the shell prompt after running the command; pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or closing the terminal instead would make the desktop unusable, and require a full restart.

From the [manual page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gnome-shell.1.html) of `gnome-shell`:

```
-r, --replace
       Replace the running window manager
```

### Unsure which version you are using?

The command to check your GNOME Shell version is:

```
gnome-shell --version
```

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure `--replace` = "restart".

Comment: As of GNOME Shell 3.30.1 on Ubuntu 18.10, this solution no longer works, and will kick the user to the login screen, losing all their work. The correct solution is now commandline: "killall -3 gnome-shell", or ALT+f2 and r (if possible).

Comment: `ALT+f2` (show command prompt) + `gnome-shell --replace` will work nicely in 18.04. All running programs won't be stopped.

Comment: I add the ampersand to the end of the command to put the process in the background so I can close the terminal without killing gnome-shell: `gnome-shell --replace &`

Comment: WARNING: `gnome-shell --replace` on my Ubuntu 19.10 machine caused most running applications to close and gnome-shell to enter a problem state with a white screen and a prompt to restart the computer.

Comment: @Sparr - thanks for the warning. Fortunately, the `killall -3 gnome-shell` answer seems to work on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: I had installed and removed a GNOME manually (via `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`), but GNOME didn't see that and Gnome Tweaks kept showing the extension as installed. Tried `gnome-shell --replace` hoping to fix the situation, but that didn't help. Only rebooting worked.

Comment: `gnome-shell --version` for checking the version, in case anyone else needs it

Comment: When `gnome-shell` v3.28.3 wasn't responding to Ctrl+Alt+F2 for me, `gnome-shell --replace` did nothing, but `killall -3 gnome-shell` did restart it without logging me out.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome version 3.36.8,  doing `killall -3 gnome-shell` forced me to login again and closed all my apps.

Answer (score 118):

The easiest way is to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `r` then <kbd>↵</kbd>.

Comment: That is true, but exactly not the question. The question then is: what happens when you do this. So that you can do it yourself

Comment: As of GNOME Shell 3.30.1 on Ubuntu 18.10, and commandline: "killall -3 gnome-shell" are the only solutions posted here that work. All others kick the user out to login screen, losing all their work.

Comment: Tried this on debian buster. Getting "Restart is not available on wayland" error.

Comment: Amazing! That was so simple on Ubuntu 19.10 :) Thank you!

Comment: This one works for me on Xorg display server. But on Wayland, for now, no way to make it work.

Comment: I get "Command 'r' not found". Anyone know what's up with that?

Comment: Seems to have worked on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Thanks!

Comment: sometimes lg stucked 

Answer (score 52):

Since GNOME Shell 3.30.1: You can also do a `killall -3 gnome-shell`.

Comment: Probably because this is a good solution where the other command doesn't work. I tried both, the choosen one is good but didn't solve my problem, while this did.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 18.10, GNOME Shell 3.30.1 - THIS IS THE CORRECT SOLUTION. All other solutions restart the session and kick the user out to the login screen, losing all their work.

Comment: SIGQUIT (3) doesn't kill the process

Comment: This seemed to work for me. Whereas I was using `gnome-shell --replace &` before. It worked but, kept running in the terminal. The issue I was having was with Youtube videos in full screen somehow causing Dash-to-Dock and the panel to freeze closed. https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/298#issuecomment-473622040

Comment: Matter of style: a Unix sysadmin might prefer `pkill -3 gnome-shell` rather than `killall`, which means something different outside of the GNU OS.

Comment: On some systems, applications will be child processes of gnome-shell, so when you restart it with this method you will STILL lose your work.

Comment: @smac89 you should remove your comment. It only serves to confuse users.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior done

Comment: You need this if Gnome Shell and desktop is freezing and cursor is the only thing that's moving. Just press Ctrl + Alt + F2 then type the above command. It was successful in 18.04.

Comment: Thank goodness for this when my xrdp session had some weird stuck Meta key issue (which I couldn't disable using the sticky keys or accessibility settings)

Answer (score 15):

In the case where the whole GNOME Shell got frozen, there is a way to restart it from the terminal without restarting the whole X window:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to a TTY terminal.
2. Log in with your credentials (username and password) and then run:

   ```
   DISPLAY=:0 gnome-shell -r &
   ```
3. Log out by running:

   ```
   exit
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch back to a graphical X windows session.

Answer (score 6):

Before GNOME Shell 3.30.1 the command should just be `gnome-shell --replace`.

Comment: As of GNOME Shell 3.30.1 on Ubuntu 18.10, this solution no longer works, and will kick the user to the login screen, losing all their work. The correct solution is now commandline: "killall -3 gnome-shell", or ALT+f2 and r (if possible).

Comment: doesn't work for a remote session, so when gnome shell has frozen, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The Gnome 40 the equivalent of `Alt+F2 restart` is:

```
busctl --user call org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell Eval s 'Meta.restart("Restarting…")'
```

Got this tip myself from https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command.html.

Comment: worked on Debian 11.0

Comment: I wanted to note that this took a few seconds (screen turned black) and then all my apps were closed on 21.10.

Comment: This doesn't work for me anymore in GNOME Shell 42.5

Comment: For Gnome Shell 43 (on Xorg), the command is now: `busctl --user call org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell Eval s 'Meta.restart("Restarting…", global.context)'`.

However, executing GJS like this is unfortunately no longer supported by default. You have to run `global.context.unsafe_mode = true` in Looking Glass first, which makes this rather unhelpful for frequent restarts

Answer (score 4):

Sending TERM signal to Gnome Shell 42.1 works for me on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
pkill -TERM gnome-shell
```

Note: TERM is the default signal for pkill.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this function to logout users (see at the bottom)

It assumes

- you have sudo permissions
- you have bash
- the users have 1 running X session (although you should be able to issue the same logout command multiple times to get rid of remaining sessions)

You can give it multiple usernames:

```bsh
logout john jane mike elisa
```

And you can give it additional options:

```bsh
logout john --force
```

So, I have the following helper function:

```bsh
function forcelogout() {
    logout "$@" --no-prompt --force
}
```

Notes:

- This is a blunt instruments and works by just copying the entire session environment. This could be more selective.
- Sometimes logout seems to take a while
- In rare occasions the session keeps being reported until someone visits the vt where the session ran, but nothing is there anymore)

#### CODE

```bsh
function logout() {
    local USERNAME
    export USERNAMES=( ) 
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do case "$1" in
        -* ) break ;;
        *) USERNAMES+=( "$1" ); shift ;;
    esac; done

    for USERNAME in "${USERNAMES[@]}"; do
        local SESSION_PID=$(pgrep -fu "$USERNAME" gnome-session|head -1)
        if [ -n "$SESSION_PID" ]; then
            (
                sudo -u "$USERNAME" cat "/proc/$SESSION_PID/environ" | xargs -0 -n 1 echo export
                echo "gnome-session-quit --logout $@"
            ) | sudo -u "$USERNAME" sh -;
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: logout USERNAME --force, gives me an output telling me a number is necessary.

Comment: @Quidam That indicates that the variable is not set to a value. You need to set it (which is what happens in the script)

Answer (score 1):

I defined an alias:
`alias gnomeshellrestart='echo "gnome-shell --replace -d" $(w| grep "$USER"| awk "{print \$3}"|grep ":"|head -1)| at now'`

You may be able to start a terminal by right-clicking with the mouse on background and type there (alt-tab is dysfct then, too), if not, login to a tty with e.g. ctrl-alt-F2 and run from there.

Answer (score 1):

In order to proper restart all related, I prefer restarts of whole stack (if tty1..4 works)

```
sudo killall -9 gdm
sudo killall -9 gdm3
sudo killall -9 lightdm
```