# How can I restart GNOME Shell, after it freezes or becomes unresponsive?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, freeze

Sometimes, my GNOME Shell freezes. I can see (hear) background processes working (playing music), but I can't do anything in GNOME. No <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> followed by <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I can switch to console using: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login as the same user and execute:

```
gnome-shell --replace
```

and return back <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but then, I get a strange behavior. For example I cannot edit network connections. I cannot logout as well. What is the proper way to restart the `gnome-shell`?

Comment: Does gnome-shell freezes while using the search-function in `gnome-shell overview`, or on what particular occasion, if you can tell?

Comment: No, it freezes after login (mostly), usually after undocking.

Comment: So far, I didn't found a working solution. In the end, I end up with [this workaround](http://phreaknerd.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/gnome-shell-reload-after-freeze/).

Comment: If you use any shell-extensions from: https://extensions.gnome.org/ deactivate all of them and reboot, to see if one of them caused the trouble. I use an older version of gnome-shell and had plenty of issues due to that exact cause! (Maybe it is just as simple as that?!)

Comment: I tried to deactivate all of them, still having the problem :(

Comment: Then I don't know! Sorry!!

Comment: I prefer: gnome-shell -r & Works great from gnome-terminal in the same display.

Comment: I finally defined an alias, which should work from any shell, in tty or other: `alias gnomeshellrestart='echo "gnome-shell --replace -d" $(w| grep "$USER"| awk "{print \$3}"|grep ":"|head -1)| at now'`

Comment: I've had this problem since at least *10 years* on Linux and Gnome, on several different computers. Both on Debian and Ubuntu. Once every month you login and after that everything is frozen except the mouse pointer and you can't do anything and nothing useful in any log file :/

Answer (score 250):

The easier way is just pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will work so long the shell is usable.

You can also send `SIGQUIT` to the `gnome-shell` process which will terminate only the shell:

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

Other methods use more destructive means, which close all the applications, this shouldn't.

Comment: +1 for the `SIGHUP` tip, however, wouldn’t the correct command then be `killall -1 gnome-shell`? At least according to [`man 7 signal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/signal.7.html), the value for `SIGHUP` is 1. Value 3 corresponds to `SIGQUIT`. I have sent value 1 to the Gnome Shell and it was cleanly restarted as expected.

Comment: @Chriki yeah, it was sigquit, through most signals would make gnome-shell process end.

Comment: I tried this on Fedora 25 and `killall -3 gnome-shell` resulted in killing all applications for me.

Comment: I wish we could also use a terminal command having exactly the same effect as `Alt+F2` and `r`, i.e. without blanking the whole screen...

Comment: This one disabled all my gnome-shell-extensions. Even after restart, they didn't back until I activated them again one by one.

Comment: @fsevenm none of these touch the shell configuration. Maybe gnome gets smart and says "well, I got terminated uncleanly, maybe I should blame one of these extensions, mmm"

Comment: You are GOD! very very Thank you!!

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20 this saved my session I would suggest using CTRL+ALT+F3 or to get into any TTY session console for the "killall -3 gnome-shell". Did not kill my other open apps.

Answer (score 47):

- If you want to ask "nicely" to gnome-shell to restart itsself, then you can call it's internal restart function over dbus with following command (assuming you have `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` env var set to the correct value and run as same user):

  ```
  dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'global.reexec_self()'
  ```
- If you want to run a new instance, `gnome-shell --replace` should do fine. On console you need to define necessary environment variables like `DISPLAY`, `DBUS*` and so on. Refer to `/proc/$gnome_shell_pid/environ`
- If you want to restart existing one, then `killall -HUP gnome-shell` will do it. If you do that too often though, gnome-shell might disable all extensions, forcefully log you off or otherwise behave in non-userfriendly manner.

Comment: I created a shell function that sets the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS from the gnome-shell process environment (so you can `logout otheruser1 otheruser2`) http://askubuntu.com/a/874504/17941

Comment: Got the error `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files` without sudo and `Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11` with sudo.

Comment: What if there is no gnome-shell running (i.e. it died)? how would one get DISPLAY and other vars

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: This is very useful for writing shell extensions

Answer (score 15):

If you have installed ubuntu gnome, which you should have, you might be using the gnome display manager. In that case you should change to another TTY, like Ctrl + Alt + F4 and then

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

I also wrote an article about such situation recently:

[Help, my Linux Desktop hangs!](https://www.steinzone.de/wordpress/help-my-linux-desktop-hangs/)

Best Luck!

Comment: **be careful**, I did it on the same TTY and this kill my current session..

Comment: this completely fucked up the current session: it started to blink and then went to nirvana.. had to reboot.

Comment: It depends on the version of Ubuntu you are using. Here it was 16.04

Comment: I agree, **be careful**! This command cause you can lost settings. For me: lost mouse settings, disabled GNOME Shell Extensions (extensions: Dash to Panel, Clock Override, Datetime Format).

Answer (score 14):

Here is a different workaround:

1. Log in a local terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Run the command:

   ```
   sudo kill -HUP $(pidof gnome-shell)
   ```
3. Return to the graphical interface by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

PS: I'm using lightdm instead of gdm3.

Comment: Simple, and works like a charm! (At least for me)

Comment: Whilst this does successfully restart gnome-shell; I find that some programs - presumably those less well integrated with GNOME - don't survive; eg: Firefox, Thunderbird, VirtualBox VMs.  Example of programs that survive: "Files", Terminal, ImageViewer.  Ideally there's be a way to restart gnome-shell without jeopardizing any running program (Ubuntu 19.10)

Answer (score 6):

Since you are not satisfied with `gnome-shell --replace`, you might want to try restarting the display manager itself.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

I think that will kill other processes you are running.
Also refer http://worldofgnome.org/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-when-freezes-if-ever/

If you are seriously into something that make you freeze everytime, enable the SysRq as mentioned in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/sysrq.rst, and then give `<alt><sysrq/print_screen_key><k>` to kill whatever its there on the screen.

Comment: Restarting lighdm works, but I want to avoid it, because I have to reopen everything from a scratch. Especially if I know it is problem of a Gnome-shell and restarting it *almost* works.

Comment: I am unaware of other methods to restrat just the gnome shell. Did you try whether `DISPLAY=:7 gnome-shell --replace` works ?

Comment: No, it does not, I use display, when `w` shows display different than *:0*. If I use a wrong display I get an error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of options. You should probably ask in the gnome user/developer mailing list. First figure out why you have abnormalities with `alt-f2-r` or `gnome-shell --replace` when it is the gnome's recommended way.

Comment: So am I. I did even followed [this link](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Debugging) setting up more ENV variables, but I still cannot edit network connections when restarting gnome-shell from a different terminal.

In the end, I end up with [this trick](http://phreaknerd.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/gnome-shell-reload-after-freeze/)

Comment: "Ended up with _this trick_" : Shall I concur that it perfectly solves your problem ?

Comment: Actually, not. It sometimes restarts the gnome-shell properly, but today it did not helped. After undocking, my gnome-shell froze, restart de-froze the shell, but I was not able to turn on the wifi :( Still my only option is *service gdm restart*.

Answer (score 4):

I do sometimes have the same problem as you describe, and my solution is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, login as same user and execute:

```
sudo pkill -9 ^gnome-shell
```

And return back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

If this is the proper way, I don't know. For me it works everytime.

Comment: This will kill all users instances of gnome-shell which may not be something you want to do in a multi-user scenario.  Normally you only have to kill your own (pkill -HUP gnome-shell)

Comment: great it works for me...! you save my day. appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

### Restart X

- First find which display manager your Ubuntu is using with following command:

  ```
  cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
  ```

  in my case it's `/usr/sbin/gdm3`

  From Inside X or OUTSIDE X
- For Method 1 to 4, find out which display you're using by using the `w` command.

  ```
  w
  ```

  the answer may be for example `tty3`,  (therefor my (ack's) "return to my display" key is Ctrl+Alt+F3

#### Methods

1. Ctrl+Alt+F1 to exit, and Ctrl+Alt+F3 to bring one back
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart`
3. `systemctl restart gdm.service`
4. `sudo service gdm3 restart`
5. `dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'global.reexec_self()'`
6. An easy way is just pressing Alt + F2, and type `r` then press Enter. This will work so long the shell isn't unusable.

Comment: Method 5 is lifted verbatim from [korc's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/672943/301745) and 6 from [Braiam's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/496999/301745). Plagiarism isn't against the rules here, but it's definitely not cool. All you really need to do is indicate that the work is not your own by putting it in quotes, and give attribution by including a link to the source post and a link to the author's profile page. For more details, see this blog post: [Attribution Required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.04 if you have ssh enabled on the affected computer.

1. ssh into the affected computer from a remote computer
2. execute `killall -1 gnome-shell` **without** sudo.

There's a bit of lag at the start when logging as it is re-instantiating all gnome objects be patient; but most if not all running programs should continue working.

Answer (score 2):

The (currently) most upvoted [answer by @Braiam](https://askubuntu.com/a/496999/1169351) misses some details. Some of the other answers didn't work for me. Hence, I am writing what did work for me. Note that this is tested on Ubuntu 20.04 running GNOME Shell 3.36.9.

0. If the current instance of GNOME Shell is still responsive, restart it with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → <kbd>r</kbd> → <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should work in most cases. But once in a while, the shell may become completely unresponsive, or even this command may get stuck. In that case, go on to the following steps.
1. Go to a TTY. On my system, the key combination would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>.
2. Log in. (Note that in TTY, number keys on numeric keypad may not work!)
3. Find the PID of GNOME Shell using `pidof gnome-shell`.
4. Kill it using `sudo kill -1 <pid>` replacing `<pid>` with the output of the above step. (If you don't use `sudo`, you will get the `Operation not permitted` error.)
5. Re-execute step 3. If nothing is returned, then GNOME Shell has not yet restarted. Keep repeating step 3 until you get the PID of the new instance of the shell. (Note that this PID will not be the same as what you had got in step 3.)
6. Once the PID of the new shell instance is returned, you can safely return to the GUI. Type `exit` and log out of the TTY.
7. Return to the GUI. In Ubuntu 20.04, this is achieved using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

This method did not close any of the applications that were running. Unsaved changes in such applications still existed without any problem. All GNOME extensions were loaded properly too.

Comment: "Re-execute step 3. If nothing is returned, then GNOME Shell has not yet restarted": No matter how long I wait no GNOME shell restarts.  Ubuntu 22.04, GNOME Shell 42.5, Wayland.

Comment: On Wayland, Gnome can't restart. You have to either use Xorg or reboot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to switch to a terminal window. Sometimes, this is
   not possible.
2. Press Alt+SysRq+R to get the keyboard.
3. If pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 before failed, try it again now.
4. Press Alt+SysRq+E to terminate all processes.
5. Press Alt+SysRq+I to kill all processes.
6. Press Alt+SysRq+S to sync your disks.
7. Wait for OK or Done message. If you don't see a message, look at your HDD light to see if Sync made a difference.
8. Press Alt+SysRq+U to unmount all disk drives.
9. Wait for OK or Done message. If you don't see a message in 15-30    seconds, assume disks are unmounted (or that an unmount is not    possible) and proceed.
10. Press Alt+SysRq+B to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

`kill -15 gnome-shell` does not work for me but `kill -9` does. I think it is because `kill -9` triggers a segfault which triggers gnome-shell to restart itself, while `kill -15` does not.

Comment: `kill -9` doesn't trigger a segfault. It sends SIGKILL, an uncatchable signal for which the only action is to quit immediately. It should only be used when the application doesn't respond to SIGTERM, which is 15.

Comment: `pkill -11 gnome-shell` would trigger a segfault, since that's literally what signal 11 does. BTW, `kill` needs a process ID, **NOT** a process name. Did you mean `pkill` or `killall`?