# Cannot exit terminal started in safe boot 16.04.

Tags: 16.04, gnome, tty

New install 16.04 froze.  Followed TTY "gnome shell --replace" which did not work. Found instructions to install Gnome extensions found here: [How to restart Gnome-shell, after it became unresponsive/freeze?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455301/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-after-it-became-unresponsive-freeze/496999). Reboot produced errors and I am stuck in safe mode, at the terminal, logged in and ready to exit politely.  System is up to date and cleaned.
I cannot exit.  I could press the big button, but I am trying to fix this install and do not want more zombies which I already have and cannot remove.  I have been reading most of the afternoon.

Comment: would it hurt to re-install clean, just suggesting!

Comment: No.  I'll give it 1 more hour.  I agree.  Nothing to lose.  Thanks.