# App Menu makes system stop

Tags: 20.04, freeze, crash, appmenu

Some times when I group or ungroup my application in the applications menu(Super + A) it freezes my laptop and then nothing works even after a 10-minute wait, as a result, I have to shut down the laptop and start it again.
I imagine if I had not saved my work and this happens at that time.

Is this problem only with me or others having this too??
Please provide some solution!!

Comment: Did you try pressing Alt+F2 and entering the command `r` in the input box?

Comment: sorry I didn't get what 'r' ??

Comment: See this for example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/455301/how-can-i-restart-gnome-shell-after-it-freezes-or-becomes-unresponsive/