# gnome-session-quit to logout does not work when run as root with sudo

Tags: command-line, logout, gnome-session

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and user name is pandya.

```
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ gnome-session-quit
```

When above command run **without** being sudo (`sudo su`) in terminal, it successfully logs out.
[image]

---

But when running after sudo (as a root),

```
root@pandya-desktop:/home/pandya# gnome-session-quit
```

It gives error :

```
** (gnome-session-quit:3168): WARNING **: Failed to call logout: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

So, because of being root, I tries to running command with `sudo -u pandya gnome-session-quit` to run command as a user pandya. But it gives same error.

Then I tries follwing to run as pandya:

```
root@pandya-desktop:/home/pandya# su pandya
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ gnome-session-quit

** (gnome-session-quit:3269): WARNING **: Failed to call logout: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

But it gives same error.

Hence, My question is: **How to logout as a root? Because I want to put `gnome-session-quit` in sctipt which is to be run as root**. (I don't want to kill forcefully process but want to normal logout prompt)

---

Further Specification:-

I have script which is to be run as root.

```
#! /bin/bash
....command to be executed.....
sudo -u pandya gnome-session-quit
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -i -u pandya gnome-session-quit`? The `-i` will emulate a terminal exactly like the user will get.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen : It also gives same error!

Comment: Is your script going to be run by root or will you use it with `sudo`? There is a difference.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen that won't work because the `-i` launches a new login shell, it does not give "a terminal exactly like the user would get" (that would be an interactive, non-login shell) but starts a new login shell instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but the reason the `sudo` command is failing is because you have started the X server as `pandya` and are not exporting pandya's environment variables that allow you to communicate with the running Gnome session.

So, this will allow you to kill your Gnome session:

```
sudo -E -u pandya gnome-session-quit
```

From `man sudo`:

> -E, --preserve-env
>
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to pre‐
>                    serve their existing environment variables.  The security
>                    policy may return an error if the user does not have permis‐
>                    sion to preserve the environment.

---

If you want to have a script that runs some commands as root and then want it to be able to log you out, you can do it as follows:

1. Create the script, without `sudo` for the privileged commands but *with* `sudo` for the logout. For example:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   apt-get install firefox
   sudo -E -u pandya gnome-session-quit
   ```
2. Run the script with `sudo -E`:

   ```
   sudo -E /path/to/script
   ```

The `sudo -E script.sh` ensures that your env variables are available to the script and the `sudo -E -u pandya` ensures that they are passed on to the `gnome-session-quit` call.

Comment: @Pandya please clarify your situation. You have mentioned `sudo su` and `sudo`. Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly which commands you are using and exactly what your script is supposed to do. These details are very important. My suggestion will work if you run it as `pandya`, not if you are already inside a root shell. I assumed you would run your script as `sudo script.sh`.

Comment: @Pandya can you come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) to discuss this? I still don't understand why you want to run that as root.

Comment: I run script with `sudo -E` so it logs out successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I've created this script that does set the DBUS session variables from the gnome-session environment in case you want to logout other users/sessions:

[How to restart Gnome-Shell from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100226/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command-line/874504#874504)

```bsh
function logout() {
    local USERNAME
    export USERNAMES=( ) 
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do case "$1" in
        -* ) break ;;
        *) USERNAMES+=( "$1" ); shift ;;
    esac; done

    for USERNAME in "${USERNAMES[@]}"; do
        local SESSION_PID=$(pgrep -fu "$USERNAME" gnome-session|head -1)
        if [ -n "$SESSION_PID" ]; then
            (
                sudo -u "$USERNAME" cat "/proc/$SESSION_PID/environ" | xargs -0 -n 1 echo export
                echo "gnome-session-quit --logout $@"
            ) | sudo -u "$USERNAME" sh -;
        fi
    done
}
```