# When accidentally dragging an icon in the taskbar it will always stay in drag mode(18.04)

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

First of all it might be worth mentioning that I moved my taskbar to the bottom of the screen instead of the left side.

Let's say that I am currently running an application like firefox. If I try to use the taskbar (dock is the Ubuntu term I think?) and I click slightly below the icon, it turns into drag mode instead of just maximizing/minimizing the application window that I clicked on.

Why is this? Is there a way to turn this feature off?

With this system I have to be so conscious every time I use the taskbar of where my cursor is at the time of clicking, whereas in Windows 10 if you click on/slightly below the application icon in the taskbar, it will always minimize/maximize the app. Is there some way to make the taskbar function in the same way it does on Windows?

But it gets worse. If I start dragging the taskbar icon, it will ALWAYS drag the icon if I click on it a second time, even though I just did a simple left click on the icon. I can't figure out for the life of me what it is expecting me to do? Unless I just close the application and restart it, I can't use the taskbar at all to minimize/maximize. It will always just keep dragging the icon instead of just maximizing the app.

Comment: Slightly longer click on app icons in the dock works same as a right click by design. Perhaps something related to that? A short video sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I got into this bug too but cannot yet understand how to replicate it. A bug report should be filled if not already.

Comment: I noticed this beaviour since Mint 18 and now 19. I know that everything is fine if I leave the taskbar on the left side. As soon as I put it to the ground I have this hand that is kept in drag and drop while clicking on things in the taskbar. After two to four clicks the desktop will then crash on me. But I have no clue why this is happening. I just found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240850/is-it-possible-to-disable-in-linux-mint-the-mouse-hand-that-moves-windows

Comment: @peterling I was able to reproduce it with taskbar on the left side.

Comment: Temporary workaround for me - restarting Gnome Shell (https://askubuntu.com/questions/100226/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command-line)

Comment: `killall -3 gnome-shell`

Answer (score 3):

This still happens. Even when using [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/).

When it happens, I click the icon and the preview comes up. Without moving mouse off, click again and the right-click/context menu comes up. Without moving mouse off, click again and the window min/maximizes. It then works as normal, until I accidentally drag again.

Has anyone found or filed a bug for this, yet?