# Icons in GNOME sidebar (dock) won't stop being dragged

Tags: mouse, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I'm having an issue where I click on an icon in the GNOME favorites bar aka Ubuntu dock (to open a window, etc.), but instead of just opening the window the icon immediately goes into drag mode for repositioning.  I know that holding the click on the icon causes drag mode, so I checked my mouse and click timings, but those all seem to be in order.  I've also made sure everything is up to date OS-wise.

Any other ideas for a fix?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME 3.28.2 on a Thinkpad T580, and I can provide other info as needed.

Comment: It's a bit random.  I'd say it occurs maybe 50% of the time I go to click on something.  (Also, thanks for the edits.)

Comment: Can you associate this issue with something else? For example, a resource hungry application is running OR high system memory/processor use OR overheating etc.?

Comment: Not that I can identify.  I've tried to determine if it occurs differently with different applications, nothing there.  No dependency on running processes, overheating, or anything like that.  I've discharged the machine's static buildup, even (which the T580 seems to have issues with, and that sometimes causes weird problems).  No pattern that I can yet see.

Comment: Did you check if your keyboard has not maintain the `ctrl` key pressed?

Comment: No issues with `ctrl`, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm also having this, it's only on one application though, an Electron app. Are you using Dash to Dock too? I notice this issue doesn't exist if I revert to using the dock in the Overview.

Comment: I'm not, Zach, no.  Good idea, though.  What kind of machine are you on?

Comment: Related - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051674/when-accidentally-dragging-an-icon-in-the-taskbar-it-will-always-stay-in-drag-mo

Comment: `killall -3 gnome-shell`

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, this fixes the issue for me:

- Open Ubuntu Settings -> Dock.
- Toggle the "Position on screen" option to some other value and back.