# How to restart X Window Server from command line and be able to login again afterwards?

Tags: 19.04

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo). My question is the same as this old one: [How to restart X Window Server from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-to-restart-x-window-server-from-command-line)

However, the much upvoted answer there does not work for me. When I run `sudo systemctl restart display-manager` as suggested there, the window system is restarted but then after that I cannot login, it seems like the window system is restarted again at each login attempt. So then I anyway need to reboot to make things work again. So that does not achieve what I want. What I would like is to be able to restart the window system without doing a full system reboot.

The other suggestion in the old answer was to check which display manager is used by doing `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` (in my case this gives `/usr/sbin/gdm3`) and then run `sudo restart gdm` but that gives me an error message: `sudo: restart: command not found`.

Is there a way to restart the X window system in Ubuntu 19.04 without doing a full reboot, and be able to login again afterwards?

Edit: I also tried `systemctl restart gdm` but that gives the same problem as `sudo systemctl restart display-manager` -- the window system is restarted but after that I cannot login, need to reboot to make things work again.

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart gdm` is the correct answer, if it does not work, then you have found a bug. What do the logs in `/var/log/gdm/`say ?

Comment: @thecarpy I have no `/var/log/gdm/` directory. There is a `/var/log/gdm3/` directory but that one is empty.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the `3` and `systemd`: what does `journalctl --since=today|grep gdm` report ?

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
systemctl restart gdm
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that now but it did not help, I have just added it as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This old Q&A: [How to restart GNOME Shell from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100226/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command-line/814336#814336) may have the answers for you.

Initially these used to work for people:

- The easiest way is to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `r` then <kbd>↵</kbd>.
- The command to replace the gnome-shell would be `gnome-shell --replace`.

Now days this seems to be the only solution:

- You can also do a `killall -3 gnome-shell`.

**Note:** This Q&A focuses on restarting gnome display manager **without** loosing all work and going back to Login screen.

---

### What does <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> do?

From: [13 Keyboard Shortcut Every Ubuntu 18.04 User Should Know](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-shortcuts/)

> **10. Alt+F2: Run console**
>
> This is for power users. If you want to run a quick command, instead
> of opening a terminal and running the command there, you can use
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to run the console.

Comment: what does alt+f2 then r mean? The complete command is? Thanks. When I use r in terminal, command not found. What window does alt+f2 open?

Comment: @WesternGun I updated the answer for your comment. What version / flavour of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I use Ubuntu 18.04. The complete output for `r` is: `Command 'r' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install r-cran-littler`

Comment: @WesternGun `r` is not a command to be run in Linux. `r` takes you to an option on `Alt`+`F2`. Does `Alt` + `F2` work for you? If not it may be your version of Ubuntu or Flavor/Desktop.

Comment: Alt+F2 works for me, I just don't know why I can simply type `r` in the command window and I thought it is equivalent to terminal, but it seems not.