# 20.04 restart frozen gnome

Tags: gnome, 20.04, freeze, tty, restart

With fresh-installed 20.04 sometimes I get almost completely frozen GUI. Almost completely -- I mean I can not do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `r`. And while the mouse pointer still moves, the system does not respond to mouse clicks or keyboard buttons.

I already have found out that in 20.04 to switch to another tty you can not use <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> in well-known <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> combination -- only <kbd>F3</kbd> and further. And to return to GUI you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> combination.

To summarize, I can switch to another text-mode tty, but how do I restart gnome-shell from there? I tried several commands, but neither succeeded. And the result was either error message or loosing the session and closing working programs. Of course, in the second case I have to wait for another freeze to test some another command. So the main question is:

How do I restart gnome-session from another tty in a way, similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `r`  **specifically in 20.04** ?

**UPD:**

Several minutes ago I got more severe freeze. I could move the mouse pointer, but the system did not respond even to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> combination, and I could not switch to another tty. So the next question:

Does the ability to move the mouse pointer mean that some part of the system is still alive and I could possibly interact with it, and how do I do it if I stuck to GUI and can not switch to another tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> combination? Again **specifically in 20.04**

Comment: does that help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/100226/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command-line

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema https://askubuntu.com/a/1239883/232433

Comment: If you'd respond to my request for more information, maybe I could help you. Also show me `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: You can re-enable the virtual terminals by calling `sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and then uncommenting `NAutoVTs=6`.

Comment: You may be able to get a command line by using alt f2 before starting gnome.

Comment: I resolved this by re-installing `gnome` .. switch to command line session using `alt + F2` before starting gnome (after starting gnome I had no response from any keys) and then follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257470/reinstall-gnome

Comment: you are NOT the only one. I have the same problem when let the computer run for 24 hours more. my solution is open terminal and kill gnome shell, then everything comes back extremely quick again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
“`RightAlt+F2 r Enter`”?

Unless it was coincidence, the LEFT Alt key did nothing.

This has been frustrating me for a long time as well.   **Left**Alt did not do anything but **Right**Alt did.

Regained responsiveness and did  not lose any apps, but the Desktop Environment or Gnome Menu disappeared.  Have to figure out the gnome-session(?) equivalent of explorer.exe.

PopOS 20.04