# Reinstall Gnome

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I tried to update from 16.04 to 20.04, and as is customary, everything went to hell. The GUI was not launching at first, but I got through that by fixing broken packages and reinstalling the linux kernel.

I can now boot into Gnome desktop and use some programs. However, I get intermittent error messages - `Sorry, Ubuntu 20.04 has experienced an internal error` with a crash in `gnome-control-center`.

[image: error]

By the way, I tried to reinstall gnome using the following command, but still see errors above.

`sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3`

How do I reinstall the Gnome GUI portion of by Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: There is no supported way to upgrade 16.04 directly to 20.04, so that was a bad idea. Perhaps you could use the recovery mode (commandline only), where you won't be bothered with with GUI crashes.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: The screenshot mentions 18.04, but you said you are using 20.04. I would recommend to boot, hit <Ctrl+Alt+F3> and run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get newest dependencies.

Comment: I updated 16.04 to 18.04, then 18.04 to 20.04.

Comment: @Serafim no luck on that. But nice suggestion!

Comment: has anyone fixed this? same problem can not launch desktop anymore can not do muych

Answer (score 2):

As this has been viewed more than 10k times (!) and people still having problems; and still no (at least not "working") answer;
If someone would have this problem again;
check my [answer on this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279979/1130604)

A snippet of it below **note - please do read the post; as it contains info about not only the problem; but some other(likely to come after) problems with Gnome/Nvidia(for example)**

---

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

or `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

one could as well as try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

---