# Command line to restart Gnome display manger

Tags: display-manager

It happens to me from time to time on Ubuntu 20.04. The screen freeze and nothing seems to work. keyboard combinations like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> are not responding. logging via ssh from another machine works fine and using htop I do not see any process that is high in RAM and/or CPU usage.

What should I do to restart the display manager (gnome) without rebooting?

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart gdm.service` if you are using systemd.

Comment: I tried @starkus suggestion. I was logged out and all applications were closed.  I do not know if this should happen.  Is there a way of refreshing  the display with out logging out. Thank you

Comment: ALT+F2 and `r`, but that's not what you are looking for I guess.

Comment: You may be interested by these answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/100226/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command-line